# Why does type deduction fail on (non-pointer-to) function types

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

Starting with some metaprogramming code:

```
template<class... Ts>
class list {}; //a generic container for a list of types

template<class in_list_type>
class front //get the type of the first template parameter
{
    template<template<class...> class in_list_less_template_type, class front_type, class... rest_types>
    static front_type deduce_type(in_list_less_template_type<front_type, rest_types...>*);
public:
    typedef decltype(deduce_type((in_list_type*)nullptr)) type;
};
```

This code works fine for this:

```
typedef typename front<list<int, float, char>>::type type; //type is int
```

But fails to compile when the first item is a function type:

```
// no matching function for call to 'deduce_type'
typedef typename front<list<void (), float, char>>::type type;
```

I only have access to XCode at the moment and can't confirm whether this is simply an XCode bug. I'm using XCode 4.5.1, using Apple LLVM compiler 4.1.

Comment: Wouldnt the function type be void(*)()?

Comment: @Nick That's the pointer to function type. void() is kinda a weird bastard stepchild type in C++, which you might see when you use std::function<void ()>. It's essentially the type you get when you dereference a function pointer.

Comment: @Brent C++ is not supposed to be used. :P (Thanks for clarifying that, I didn't know about it.)

Comment: @KerrekSB And `list<A,B,C>` is indeed one argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the template arguments to `deduce_type` are being deduced, `front_type` has `void()` as a candidate. However this would make `deduce_type` have type `void ()()` (function returning a function -- `alias<void()>()` if you assume `template<typename T> using alias = T;` to be in scope). This is an error and type deduction fails.

A solution is to have `deduce_type` return something like `identity<front_type>`, and `type` be an alias to `typename decltype(deduce_type((in_list_type*)nullptr))::type`.

Comment: Beat me to it. I would add only that SFINAE is why you get a "no matching function" error instead of a "you can't use that return type" error.

Comment: @Kevin : Because a function cannot be returned as a value, only a pointer to a function. A function signature is useful only as a type, not as an object.

Comment: Functions are explicitly prohibited from having e.g. array types and function types as return types.